# How do I share my ideas without being scooped?

Tags: postdocs, early-career

I finished grad school and now I will probably be an adjunct but will apply for postdocs again. I want to talk about my research ideas with other people but I am worried that postdocs will work on them, and senior faculty with share the ideas with their own grad students who are looking for projects to work on. How can I share my ideas without this happening?

Answer (score 13):

Basically you can't prevent it. Ideas are free to use. I assume that in "sharing" your ideas you are also hoping to get (and utilize) the "ideas" of others. This is fine.

But you don't need to be an "idea faucet". You can seek collaborations with people and share the key ideas with them. Collaborations are valuable at any stage of a career, but especially so early on since you don't have the support of an advisor anymore.

However, "stealing" ideas is fairly rare. People have their own ideas to work on. The world is there to be explored.

---

For completeness, it is necessary to acknowledge some kinds of "ideas" to avoid plagiarism charges.

Comment: "stealing" ideas is fairly rare [citation needed]

Comment: Stealing ideas is fairly rare [citation needed]

Comment: @CaptainEmacs … but - just like nuclear accidents - it is often devastating when it happens.  I have witnessed (more than once) the devastation left in the wake of this kind of unethical behaviour.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Exactly. That's why I requested a citation for the "fairly rare" claim. Because it's not that unheard of either (see my comment further down).

Comment: Actually, I did a search on google for examples and came up with exactly zip in academia. If they weren't rare you would hear a lot more about it (not just here) and if it were all valid, rather than misunderstandings, you'd probably see more stabbings and attempted murder at conferences. I can't remember the last one, actually. Some of the valid cases are by people who had an idea but didn't follow up on it or put it off for too long and then "woke up" when it appeared. And, of course, I don't claim that it doesn't exist or is "extremely" rare. Yes it exists, yes it is bad. Not ubiquitous.

Comment: @Buffy this is (in part) because students have minimal if not infinitesimal leverage in pleading their cases against more senior people.  In one case I know, postdoc Bob sent a draft of his newest manuscript to his previous supervisor Charlie, who produced a slight variation on the result and submitted to a “fast journal” without acknowledging the work of Bob and co-worker.   Charlie now gets the bulk of the credit for the result, Bob and co-worker Alice and Eve are no longer in academia.

Comment: I am also familiar with multiple (>2, <10) instances of supervisor Bob presenting (at conference)as his or her own work by graduate student Alice without acknowledging Alice in any way because “Bob had the idea”…. Alice is now out of academia…

Comment: The point is: if you have an unscrupulous supervisor or collaborator and you are junior, you are defenceless against this kind of behaviour.  Even if you are senior, the leverage differential is simply moved to a differential in institutional prestige.

Comment: What you describe is less a problem of stealing because of "sharing ideas" and more one of unscrupulous advisors. IIRC you are a fairly senior person. Are you working to make it stop? Nor do you indicate whether you are writing about only a few people or a mob.

Comment: My experience is much the opposite. Supervisors giving ideas to students and then standing back for the student to run with it.

Comment: @Buffy I count between 2 and 10 cases that I know of, depending on where you draw the line, over ~ 30 years.  It’s impossible to estimate the numerator or denominator, but I never thought the numerator would be that big.  I was never in a situation where I could do something about such a case: either happened elsewhere, or I was too junior to do much better than the student.

Comment: There are certainly cases where the unscrupulous person was not a supervisor.  I know of only one case where there were consequences: because an assistant prof had pretty much “borrowed” an idea from someone else without acknowledgment, the perpetrator was denied tenure.

Answer (score 8):

There is the often stated claim that "ideas are cheap, execution is expensive" - that is not entirely true; it definitely depends on the situation. I therefore do not fully agree with my co-respondents that the risk of stealing ideas is small. It does definitively happen, rarer than one may fear, but more frequently than one may hope.

For instance, there are very simple ideas, relatively low-hanging fruits, which are comparatively easy to execute, but which have a large impact. A classic example is high-temperature conductivity where the core idea is so simple that the authors sent it to a lower-tier journal with a trusted editor and to the NYT rather than to the top journals where the short review turn-around time would have been sufficient to replicate and scoop the core insight. This is not a completely atypical example. So, it is definitely a good idea to be careful with the ideas you consider to be critical for your future.

**What to do?** Share ideas with people you trust and share different ideas with different groups of people. That way you do not put all your eggs in one basket.

That being said, do not be paranoid about ideas, that is not going to do you any good; you simply do not want to be taken advantage of. You can be generous with ideas you either do not have time to pursue or you do not consider essential for your career/development.

And sometimes, you just have to take the plunge and the risk; accept that you might fail to judge a collaborator correctly sometimes; insofar I agree with the other respondents, the times where it works out, will outnumber the cases where it doesn't, if you are a perceptive person.

Scientific friendships are built on trust. Many of them can last a lifetime.

Good luck!

Comment: “but more frequently than one may hope” — [citation needed]  From what I know it's in fact *extremely* rare. Nonetheless, good answer!

Comment: @KonradRudolph Citation's a fair request: Experience of myself and of colleagues, furthermore attempts to scooping that were prevented by explicit intervention; sabotage of paper review processes by slowing them down for competitor papers to overtake them. From my perspective this is not that common that one should fall into paranoia, but it is definitely not that absolute rarity. From this perspective, it would be disingenious to not mention this to OP and rather pretend it does not exist. Maybe other fields are quieter.

Answer (score 4):

If an idea is developed enough to run with it and write a paper, do so. Only share the key insights with your collaborators, if any.

Less well-formed ideas are unlikely to be worth stealing. In doing research, much of the hard work consists of taking projects from the idea stage to the ready-to-write-a-paper stage. For established researchers, ideas are cheap because they have more good ideas than they have time to pursue. For early-career researchers, good ideas for projects are not cheap, but everyone tries to get suggestions from as expert/senior a source as possible. So I agree with Buffy that the risk of anyone stealing your ideas, even good ones, is small.